# Changing citation delimiters

Tags: citing, punctuation

The default citation delimiter is `,`. For instance,

```
\cite{John96, Doe78, White05}
```

generates something like `[8, 2, 4]`, where the citation numbers (8, 2, and 4) are separated by a comma (`,`).

This is very natural in Latin languages, but some other languages use different delimiters. Let's assume you want to change the delimiter to, say `+`. How do you do that?

Comment: Do you mean in the _input_ or in the _output_? The two look the same here, but that is simply because using `,` is a convention in both areas.

Comment: @Joseph: I meant in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine the `\@citex` macro. In the following example, I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to change only parts of the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@citex}{,\penalty\@m\ }{+}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{A01,B02}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The commas are directly used in the internal LaTeX macro `\@citex`. You can redefine this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\citedelimiter}{+}
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{\citedelimiter\penalty\@m}%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{John96, Doe78, White05}
\end{document}
```

Extension packages may provide macros for that purpose.

Here's the output, with question marks since the citations are undefined, but you see the new delimiters:

[image]

Compared to the original LaTeX source, I changed the line

```
{\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
```

to

```
{\@citea\def\@citea{\citedelimiter\penalty\@m}%
```

I introduced the macro `\citedelimiter` to allow easy changes, what the original LaTeX did not foresee. Patching, such as suggested by lockstep, is an elegant and short way, though it may fail if the original macro would be changed, for instance by another package. At least your own redefinition may still work then, however I would also take care and check and work at the new macro, which has been redefinied by another package.

Comment: +1. Both of the answers (yours and lockstep's) provide excellent solutions. As you described, your answer is more robust, but at the cost of being more complex. I accepted lockstep's answer since it is shorter and more suitable to my environment; however, I advise any serious TeX-er to adopt Stefan's solution.